# SFML2 application cannot find shared objects

Tags: c++, sfml

I downloaded and compiled SFML2 from git ( debug, release, static and dynamic ) and I successfully compile some sample code from their tutorial using:

```
g++ main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

The problem occurs when I try to run the binary, it can't find any shared objects (libsfml-graphics.so.2, libsfml-window.so.2 etc)

I checked and they are present in /usr/local/lib.

Am I missing something?

Using Fedora 17 x64 and g++ 4.7.2 if that's relevant

Comment: `/usr/local/lib` is normally not searched by the dynamic linker. Add it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH or use `ldconfig`. This could also be 32/64 bit issue. Run `file <somtething>.so` and `file <your-executable>` to determine their architecture.

Comment: Adding it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH worked. Post this as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib` is normally not searched by the dynamic linker. Add it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Alternatively, configure the dynamic linker to always search `/usr/local/lib` and perhaps  `/usr/local/lib64`. This is usually done by adding the paths to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file, and running `ldconfig`.

There is sometimes also a 32/64 bit issue, that is, one tries to run a 32-bit executable and only 64-bit libraries are present, or vice versa. Run `file <somtething>.so` and `file <your-executable>` to determine their architecture. In general, 32-bit libraries go to `<whatever>/lib` and 64-bit ones to `<whatever>/lib64`, but sometimes they end up in a wrong place.